# HIVE - group by date function

Tags: date, hadoop, group-by, hive

Can anyone tell me why I'm not getting counts for each f0, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE group in my result set?

Result set:

[image: result set]

Query:

```
SELECT t.f0, MONTH(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))), DAY(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))), HOUR(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))), MINUTE(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))), COUNT(DISTINCT t.f1)  
FROM table t  
WHERE (t.f0 = 1 OR t.f0 = 2)  
AND (t.f3 >= '2013-02-06' AND t.f3 < '2013-02-15')   
AND (Hex2Dec(t.f2) >= 1360195200 AND Hex2Dec(t.f2) < 1360800000)  
AND *EXTRA CONDITIONS*  
GROUP BY t.f0, MONTH(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))), DAY(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))),   HOUR(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2))), MINUTE(TO_DATE(Hex2Dec(t.f2)))
```

Schema:

f0    INT (Partition Column)
f1    INT
f2    STRING
f3    STRING (Partition Column)
f4    STRING
f5    STRING
f6    STRING
f7    MAP`<STRING,STRING>`

*f2 is a unix timestamp in Hexadecimal format

Comment: Can you share some details about your input data? Right now I see only the query and the output, it's quite hard to figure out what's wrong in  your query without knowing what you're applying it to.

Comment: @Charles: Normally, I'd agree with you about lack of details.  However, the data source that I'm dealing with is proprietary and I'd rather be on the "safe" side even if I risk ambiguity and/or vagueness in my question.

Comment: did you get any data with out group by?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be because **to_date** returns null when it's applied on a unix time.
According to the [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions):

> to_date(string timestamp): 
> Returns the date part of a timestamp
>   string: to_date("1970-01-01 00:00:00") = "1970-01-01"

Use **from_unixtime** instead to get back the correct date parts.

Note:
I assume Hex2Dec UDF is taken from the core library of [HIVE-1545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1545)